Probability of randomly guessing 10 out of 14 football results
Can anyone help me with this question? After weeks of trying no one answered me across various web sites. The most important thing, I want to see and practice step by step all the calculations possible as I'm new to math.
Let's say I predict 10 football results. Each match with equal chances of being 1, X or 2. Home, Draw or Away, each with equal chance 1/3.
What is the probability of randomly guessing any 10 out of the 14 total results?
There's a similar question on here with some binomial coefficient or binomial probability but I have no idea how to calculate that formula step by step
Thanks a lot!

Do you mean exactly 10 or at least 10?  // If your issue concerns computing binomial coefficients (or multinomial coefficients, which give the solution here) that's something you can look up.  For instance, the Wikipedia article on the multinomial theorem will help.

I meant exactly 10 guesses out of a total of 14. Any 10 matches. Guessing 14 is easy, 3 to the power of 14 which is 1 in 4,782,969 chance. But any lesser than 14 is beyond me, you'd have to take into consideration the remaining matches. At my place no one knows even how to start calculating that and that wiki article is too advanced for me, that's why I was hoping someone would explain here step by step all the calculations done.

If you are willing to assume equal probabilities for each of the 3 outcomes (as stated in the question), then the problem becomes much easier. This is because you can reduce the problem to a simple Binomial distribution calculation where
$$X_i = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{Guess $i$ is incorrect (with prob $\frac{2}{3}$)} \\
1, & \text{Guess $i$ is correct (with prob $\frac{1}{3}$)}
\end{cases}$$
In this case, the number of correct guesses is $X = (X_1+X_2+\ldots + X_n)$, and you can use the straightforward and easy to understand formula
$$P(X = x) = \binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}.$$
Since you asked for a step by step explanation, here is a description of each part of the expression above:

$p^x$ gives the probability of guessing $x$ games correctly.
$(1-p)^{n-x}$ gives the probability of guessing the remaining $n-x$ games incorrectly.
$\binom{n}{x} = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$ accounts for all possible "arrangements" of outcomes that leads to getting exactly $10$ games correct. For instance, you could get the first $10$ correct, or the last $10$, etc. You already have some intuition for this, as you mentioned that the case for $n=x=14$ is easy... this is because there is only one possible arrangement... that is $\binom{14}{14} = 1$.


Using the numbers you provide above, we set $n=14$, $x=10$ and $p=1/3$ to get
$$P(X=10) = \binom{14}{10}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4 \approx 0.00335.$$

If you want to move away from equal probabilities then you will need to understand the Multinomial distribution. There are many resources online including many questions on this site for better understanding this.

Perfect, now I understand it perfectly. I only have remaining one issue: If I calculate the chances of guessing only 1 out of 14 the result is One in 41.7, which is an extremely low chance, of course given the consideration that only 1 match has to be guessed. My question is what's the formula for guessing at least 1 out of 14?

I'm sure you mean the probabilities must add to $1$..

@Lauren B. Generally, you would calculate all possibilities and add them together... $P(X=1) + P(X=2) + \ldots + P(X=14)$. But there's a shortcut! Since the probabilities must add to 1, it is faster to calculate 1−(=0).

Following on @knrumsey's answer, another interpretation of "What is the probability of randomly guessing any 10 out of the 14 total results?" is that it includes the probability of 10 correct guesses and greater than 10 correct guesses.  The OP clarified that they meant exactly 10 out of 14, but in common language for most games, people normally mean 10 or more.  If 10 correct guesses is good enough, then more also works.  Another way of thinking about it is that in a situation when someone got 14 right answers, they also got 10 right answers, just not exactly 10.
$$\sum_{k=10}^{14} P(X = k) = \sum_{k=10}^{14} {14 \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{14-k} = \\3.348548 \mathbf{x} 10^{-03} + 6.088269\mathbf{x} 10^{-04} + 7.610336\mathbf{x} 10^{-05} + 5.854104\mathbf{x} 10^{-06} + 2.090752\mathbf{x} 10^{-07} = 0.00404\\$$
